# fixing transparent youtube control icons with existing links

Tags: api, firefox, youtube, embed, ytplayer

Something happened few weeks ago that i was unable to tackle myself. There is no information regarding my problem so i have to ask for help.

We have a simple youtube videos embed in our site. However the control icons refuse to show except the one that controls the "mute". The links clearly exists as when you mouse over them you see the popup.
It is not a player size problem since i tried it all.

The problem didn't existed few weeks ago so this is something new and totally over my head. Please help.

I am including a link to a simple html with single embedded video that shows the problem. -> [Here](http://www.songfacts.com/youtubeplayertest.html)

The code itself is this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=madonna%20la%20isla%20bonita" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

ps1. I have checked this with Edge and Safari and so far this problem only exists when videos are loaded by Firefox (43.0.4)

ps2. I have updated to Firefox 44.0 and problem still exists.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any luck solving it?

Comment: Nope. It appears that Firefox is the sole problem for this. I guess we wait for patch to fix it. However it already made me switch to Chrome. So sad about FF:(